# how to define a textbox value null = 0 and has a value = 1? with javascript

Tags: javascript

sorry im noob on JS i need help
i want to try make a textbox checker that can be check the value of the textbox. when it has a value higher than 0 then has a value = 1, but when it has null value or 0 value then it has a value = 0

this my code

```
// JavaScript Document

    function check()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('s1').value=="0" 
             || document.getElementById('s1').value==undefined)
            {

                return 0;
                document.getElementById('avr').value = result;
            }
            return 1;
                document.getElementById('avr').value = result;

        }
```

Comment: The `.value` will be a string. If the field is empty it will be `""`, not `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: A `return` statement exits the function immediately, so the `...('avr').value = result` lines in your code can never be executed. Also, if those lines were *before* the `return` statements you'd still have a problem because `result` is not defined (at least, not in the code shown).

Comment: null == 0 and any number higher than 0 == 1? Seem like a boolean value to me, Not sure what you are trying to achieve but I would use Hidden field type checkbox and create a listener to that textbox

Comment: thx guy's i'm just figure it out,. and i'm just solve my problem a min ago

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the element's value before you return. A return statement terminates the execution of a function:

```
function check()
{
  if (document.getElementById('s1').value === '0' || document.getElementById('s1').value === '') {
    document.getElementById('avr').value = result;
    return 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('avr').value = result;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: The test for `undefined` won't work. Should be a test for an empty string.

Comment: Sure, just giving the basic answer to his problem.